# Checking if a group of data exist in the sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, transactions

I was asked to do copy of a csv file(which resides on a server and is updated everyday) into the database but a group of 5-6 field are the parameter which will decide whether we can enter the data or not.
The condition for insertion is that if it is a completely new entry then it will be entered if it is a copy then skip that row and if it is a different entry then update the entry in the database.

Can someone help me with how can I do this? can I do `if exist` query but that will be a costly operation as it has to match every record? Or any `SSIS` activity might help with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can make form this query MERGE and when matched do nothing
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/